# Is there a way to say what a letter "states?"

Tags: word-usage

I understand that one could write, "In the letter, the author clearly stated that he found his red hat."

But is it possible to say what the letter stated, or says? Both "stated" and "says" sound like something a person does. Is there a word for saying what a letter has written upon it? (e.g. "the letter reads that..."

Comment: Are you talking about the letter itself - the physical piece of paper with ink on it?  Or are you talking about the author of the letter - the person who uses the letter in order to get across the idea?  We normally impute the intent of the author to the physical thing, so "states", "says", "is written" all work.

Comment: Have you looked in a thesaurus yet? What did you find? Why didn't those words work for your context?

Comment: You can say *the letter states* just as you can *the answer states* or *the question asks*.

Comment: I did google for synonyms, Kevin Workman, but all that I saw in the results were synonyms. I was hoping that there would be a word that better describes what I was wondering about. I though that "the letter states" seems odd. I somewhat feel that there should be a new word for what the letter "says."

Comment: @LedZepp The documents can 'say' or 'state'. And they are referred to in this manner all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Having a letter say something is an example of a rhetorical device called *metonymy*. Metonymy is a type of metaphor where one thing stands for another. In your example, the letter stands for the author. Figuratively speaking, the letter *is* the author. This is commonly done in English. Some examples of metonymy:

- The **radio** [*radio announcer*] has just reported a storm in the area.
- The **Kremlin** [*Russian government*] issued a statement.
- The **pen** [*speech*] is mightier than the **sword** [*force*].
- Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your **ears** [*attention*].

#### Further reading

“[Metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy)” at *Wikipedia*.